# JavaScript's location.reload() behaves differently on local Apache and on live-server. Reasons?

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I'm programming a web-app which uses text-boxes for the following purposes: Insert data (by the user), display the results.

The app is used this way:

The user inserts data, an exec button is clicked. The result is calculated and presented to the user in text-boxes.

Now the user can click a reset-button for to move the app to it's initial state. So that a new usage becomes possible.

The JavaScript which is triggered by the reset-button:

```
wr.reset.addEventListener('click', function() { 
  location.reload(); 
})
```

I used these code with the local Apache-installation which I use for developing. Everything was fine. The page was reloaded. **The textboxes where all set to their initial state** => the hyphen which I define as "value".

```
<div class="vertical-pair col-xs-4"> 
  <label for="word-count">Complete word-count:</label> 
  <input type="text" id="word-count" value=" - " /> 
</div>
```

Now I've tried out the app on a real server (runned by a webhoster) and had the following result:

The page was reloaded but the content of the input-boxes persisted.

Means: **The data** which the user has entered **are still in the boxes** after executing the reset-button.

What causes these different behaviours (on the local Apache-installation and on the live-server)?

Currently I have replaced 'location.reload()' to 'location.href = "URL of the page itself"'.

Is this aproach a valid alternative or does it have flaws?

Comment: Afaik, FF has this behavior. Are you sure you use same browsers?

Comment: Try `location.reload(true)`

Comment: I use Firefox indeed. But it was BOTH times Firefox which I used for testing. And locally it worked.

Comment: May be locally your cache was disabled anyway. Use `true` argument to force reload.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) If you like: Made your comment to an answer. So that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `true` first argument to disable browser cache on reload.

**Syntax:**

> location.reload(forcedReload);

**Parameters**

> **forcedReload** *Optional*
>   Is a Boolean flag, which, when it is true, causes the page to always be reloaded from the server. If it is false
>   or not specified, the browser may reload the page from its cache.